# Where on Stack Exchange can I ask questions about internships?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange

I've looked through some of the sites, and I don't know where's a good place to ask questions about data science research opportunities?

Comment: Ask what about them?

Comment: It's very hard to answer this without knowing more about the particulars of your question. If you're asking about general job-hunting advice, [Workplace.se] might be able to help, but please read their help center first. If you're looking to get hired, try [SO Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs). If you're looking for individual advice, it's off-topic on the entire network.

Answer (score 3):

You question could also be on-topic in [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions).

Be sure to read the [tour](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) so your question is well-received and you may get help.

There on TWP you can ask almost anything that is workplace-related, and that includes internships (we even have a tag for that). Just, make sure you ask something answerable. If you pretend to ask *"Where can I find Data Science internships"* I'm afraid that will be off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Your question *may* be on topic on [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)

> If you have a question about a decision you need to make, please focus on how to make the decision, the pros and cons of a certain choice, or what relevant aspects you should consider. We cannot possibly know or judge all the details of your situation, in particular your personal preferences and the quality of your work and qualifications. Therefore you still have to make the decision yourself. Also, consider which details may be really important for what you wish to know. Try to extract the fundamental question from the specific problem at hand. As a rule of thumb, to attract answers that are most helpful to you, ask a question that would also help others in a similar situation.

See https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Note that what is definitely *not* on topic on Academia would be requests for lists or suggestions of particular opportunities.